# "Follow us" translated as "siga-nos" or "acompanhe-nos"?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês, palavra-para-ideia

It's from my understanding that [*seguir*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/seguir) resembles **tracking** more than **accompanying** someone, as if one is leading and the other(s) is(are) going after.

If I were to use a translation of "follow us" connoting a group of people going along with the "social progress" of the organization instead of tracking or going after their stuff (news, products, etc.), is the verb *[acompanhar](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/acompanhar)* a proper replacement of *seguir*?

Comment: I'm somewhat lost. Could you give us a sample text where *follow* has the exact meaning you have in mind?

Comment: @Jacinto this would be an isolated expression to be used in a button/link, more specifically for a marketing context, with an introduction similar to: "want to be a part of the first ...?"

Comment: I see. Wouldn't *junte-se a nós* be better. It is still not clear to me *follow us* means in that context. Keep checking what we're doing?

Comment: Oh, "join us" didn't occur to me, that's a plausible alternative, thanks!

Comment: I would be more than happy to have a go at a proper answer. But I'm still unsure about what the website is inviting visitors to do. You make it sound like a business secret.

Comment: @Jacinto it's ok, I am trying to relate the action button to the act of following an organization on social networks. Normally in English is the "follow us" button and I was thinking about _acompanhar_ instead of _seguir_ as an equivalent translation in Portuguese. _Juntar_ seems also a good alternative.

Comment: Você conhece a rede social Twitter? Em inglês, o botão para seguir uma pessoa está escrito "follow", enquanto em português-br está "seguir", pois você estará inscrito e de certo modo "seguindo" as publicações da pessoa em questão. Logo, se o sentido que você quer dar é para a pessoa ficar a par de atualizações ou novos produtos de uma determinada empresa nesse botão, a expressão "seguir" pode ser usada sem problemas. Se quiser um termo mais explicativo, pode usar algo como "Acompanhar novidades". "Juntar" tem ambiguidade nesse caso: pode dar a entender sobre contratar novos empregados/usuários

Comment: Em português (principalmente muitos sites pt-BR) usamos muito o termo "junte-se a nós" para contratar novas pessoas, e "inscreva-se" para que uma pessoa cadastre-se no site como usuário.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible Portuguese equivalents to:

> Follow us on social networks

are:

> (a) *Acompanhe-nos nas redes sociais* (134,000 results on Google search + 71,000 *nos acompanhe*).
>
> (b) *Siga-nos nas redes sociais* (704,000 results on Google search + 65,800 *nos siga*).

In the sense of paying attention to ongoing events, *seguir* and *acompanhar* are largely synonyms, to the point that Aulete digital, for instance often uses *seguir* to explain *acompanhar* and vice-versa:

> [***Acompanhar***](http://www.aulete.com.br/acompanhar) **15.** Manter o foco ou a atenção em; OBSERVAR [td. : *Acompanhava com atenção o discurso do candidato*.: "*A inocente D. Joaninha os acompanhou com os olhos.*" ( J. Manuel de Macedo , A moreninha) ] **18.** Seguir o desenvolvimento, a progressão de (eventos, novela, processo etc.) [td. : *Acompanhou a novela desde o primeiro capítulo*.: *O público pôde acompanhar o escândalo pela televisão*.]
>
> [***Seguir***](http://www.aulete.com.br/seguir) **4.** Acompanhar com o pensamento. [td. : *Seguia passo a passo o desenvolvimento da crise*.]
> **5.** Acompanhar com atenção. [td. : *Seguia atentamente as palavras do orador*.]

In my undestanding though, *acompanhar* conveys more emotional involvement than *seguir*. This comes probably from the other meanings of the words. *Acompanhar* means walk alongside, walk with while keeping company, whereas *seguir* means walk after or behind, maybe at a distance.

The other alternative

> *Junte-se a nós nas redes sociais* (no results on Google search).

invites more active participation in something, such as becoming a member of a club or signing a petition for something.

Comment: Estranho não encontrar a frase tão comum "Venha conosco" entre as respostas

Comment: @jean Não me ocorreu. Faria sentido na primeira página dum website como convite para explorar o resto do site. Não estou tão seguro que faça sentido como convite para acompanhar as atividades da organização nas redes sociais. Isto são só umas ideias sem muita reflexão por trás. Mas há sempre espaço para mais uma resposta :)

Answer (score 2):

*Acompanhar* não me parece grande opção. Substituamos *Facebook* por outra coisa:

> (1) Acompanhe as nossas notícias no boletim semanal.
>   (2) Acompanhe-nos no boletim semanal.

A frase (1) não levanta qualquer problema. *Acompanhar* tem estes significados próximos, em que não há noção de *companhia* (Houaiss, ed. de 2003 da Temas e Debates):

> **12** *t.d.* observar, manter a atenção ou interesse voltado para (algo, ou alguém, que está em desenvolvimento, mudança, acção ou actividade) durante um período de tempo e, eventualmente, participar do processo ou interferir nele (*<acompanhou-a com o olhar*> <*a experiência em laboratório permitiu acompanhar todas as fases do fenómeno*>
>   **15** *t.d.* tomar consciência ou conhecimento de <*acompanhar as notícias*>
>   **16** *t.d.* presenciar, assistir a (esp. algo que é exposto ou apresentado, ou a uma sucessão de eventos, episódios, o desenvolver de um facto, história, drama etc.) <*acompanhar uma telenovela*>

Crucialmente, e como nos exemplos do Aulete que o Jacinto dá, este *acompanhar* não customa selecionar argumentos com traço humano ou que digam respeito a grupos de pessoas (*equipa*, *organização*), a não ser que seja claro que haja **movimento**/**desenvolvimento** (significado **12**). Nestes sentidos, acompanham-se *processos*, *evoluções*, *trabalho*, *ritmo*, *situação*, *movimento*, *tendência*, *caso*, *desenvolvimento*, *operação*, *obra*, etc.

O significado **12** parece-me ser próximo de *monitorizar* (*neste estudo, acompanhámos cinco doentes após terem alta*) e o mais próximo de legitimar (2); o problema do significado **12** é que não é óbvio que haja qualquer movimento/desenvolvimento na **organização em si**.

Falando de uma pessoa ou de um grupo de pessoas, temos outro significado relevante para esta pergunta.

> **2** t.d. *p.ext.* conviver ou compartilhar as mesmas situações com, ou ser companheiro de <a família acompanhou-o sempre>

Mas este significado **2** parece-me ter uma ideia de suporte, ajuda, companheirismo que é demasiado forte nesta situação (*acompanhou-a/esteve ao lado dela nos momentos difíceis*). Outro problema de interpretar (2) no significado **2** (um uso por extensão do significado *normal* de *acompanhar*) é que é difícil conceber *estarmos ao lado de alguém no boletim*,

Note-se que teríamos exatamento o mesmo problema com *seguir*:

> (3) Siga as nossas notícias no boletim semanal.
>   (4) Siga-nos no boletim semanal.

A diferença é que *seguir* adquiriu um significado novo no contexto das redes sociais (=subscrever conteúdos publicados por dada entidade). Conforme os números apresentados pelo Jacinto, *acompanhar* está uma ordem de grandeza abaixo.